# RSpec mocking response attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm stuck with a small issue which I can't seem to find on the RSpec Doc (or elsewhere). I suspect it's probably to do because it's trying an HTTP call but unsure.

I'm currently attempting to mock a response in my controller, the actual response is coming straight from aws-sdk (so it's an external service).

Controller:

```
response = {
  snapshot_id: client.copy_snapshot({foo, bar}).snapshot_id
}
```

Is it possible to stub .snapshot_id?

_spec.rb

```
before do
  allow(client).to receive(:copy_snapshot).and_return('Something')

  put :update, format: :json
  puts JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

The tests passes successfully without adding .snapshot_id on the controller page and I can see

```
{"snapshot_id"=>"Something"}
```

Otherwise I get "this resource is currently unavailable." adding it in, I'm slightly lost if I'm doing it wrong or if this is intended behavior.

The reasoning is that when the server is on I will actually get a response back, however omitting snapshot_id causes the server to hang as amazon returns back a lot of data (headers, etc)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use the VCR gem to record the actual the actual response to test against if it were me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a whirl. The only issue is that the aws-sdk gem doesn't allow me to see all the 'naked' urls as they're built into the gem and I just call them like the example above.